# Ajax post works for empty ASP.net web app, but if same code is used for Web Forms project, it causes a 401 error

Tags: ajax, post, visual-studio-2019, http-status-code-401

I am having an issue submitting data using the script below.  The post will work fine if the Visual Studio (2019) project is an EMPTY ASP.Net Web Application, but if I use the same script for a Web Forms ASP.Net Web Application project, it gives me a 401 error.

In both cases, the web site is set for anonymous authentication, and when I look at the web logs between both projects, one difference that stands out is that on the Web Forms project that does not work, it is dropping the page extension.  Could this be causing iis to try to access a folder (which does not exist) instead of the file?  If so, what is causing the extension to drop and how do I fix this?

IIS log for Web Forms Project (No Good)

2020-06-23 15:14:34 ::1 POST /final.aspx/ChangeDescription - 44391 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/83.0.4103.106+Safari/537.36+Edg/83.0.478.54 https://localhost:44391/**final** 401 0 0 157

IIS log for Empty Project (Good)

2020-06-23 15:09:42 ::1 POST /final.aspx/ChangeDescription - 44361 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/83.0.4103.106+Safari/537.36+Edg/83.0.478.54 https://localhost:44361/**final.aspx** 200 0 0 124

```
<script>
    $("#NewDesc_SaveButton").click(function (e) {

        if ($("#NewDesc_TextBox").val() == "") {
            $("#NewDesc_Span").text("Enter New Description");
        }
        else {
            $("#NewDesc_Span").text("");
        }
        if ($("#NewDesc_TextBox").val() != "")
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST", url: "final.aspx/ChangeDescription", contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", data: '{"NewDescription":"' + $("#NewDesc_TextBox").val() + '"}', dataType: "json", success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                    if (result.d == "Success") { $("#StatusMsgSpan").text("New Description Has Been Saved."); setTimeout(function () { $('#ChangeDesc_Modal').modal('hide'); }, 2000); }
                    else $("#StatusMsgSpan").text("New Description Not Saved.");
                }, error: function (xhr, status, error) { $("#dbData").html("Result: " + status + " " + error + " " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText) }
            });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the assistance of a colleague, it turns out I needed to change settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent to settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off in the App_Start RouteConfig.cs file.

Make sure you clear the browser cache before you test the change.